# Should I use "like" or "as if" before a statement containing a preposition?

Tags: prepositions

Should I use "like" or "as if" before a statement containing a preposition?

Such as,

> John and Jane went together like/as if peas in a pod.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both the variants described can be seen as deleted forms:

> *John and Jane went together like peas in a pod.*
>
> *John and Jane went together like peas in a pod go together.*

...........

> John and Jane went together as if peas in a pod.
>
> John and Jane went together as if they were peas in a pod.

There's little to choose between these (original) paraphrases, other than that the one using 'like' is more common and hence sounds more natural.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the words 'like' or "as if" to connect the two parts of a sentence. In your sample, you are connecting the subject/predicate with a prepositional phrase. Your sentence should state "like peas in a pod" as "peas in a pod" is a direct object.

Comment: Thanks. While on the subject, does this mean I should always use "like" when connecting subject/predicate to a prepositional phrase? (such as the original example)

Comment: Are you comparing the two parts of the sentence?